# Sass / Scss: Changing the order of nested psuedo selectors for :before and :hover in generated CSS?

Tags: sass, compass-sass

Given the following Sass:

```
div.test {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
    &:before {
        & { 
            &:hover {
                border: 1px solid salmon;
            }
        }
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        content: "";
    }
}
```

The resulting CSS compiles to:

```
div.test {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
}

    div.test:before {
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        content: "";
    }

        div.test:before:hover {
            border: 1px solid salmon;
        }
```

What I am attempting to do is generate *div.test:**hover:before*** (the current output is **before:hover**).

**NOTE:**  I am able to generate the expected CSS by using the following Sass:

```
div.test {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
    &:hover {
        &:before {
            border: 1px solid salmon;
        }
    }

    &:before {
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        content: "";
    }
}
```

However I would like to know if it is possible using the first nested approach or some modification of it.

The goal was to avoid having to repeat &:before if there was such a way to do so using Sass syntax.  I am also OK with knowing it isn't possible.

Comment: Why does it matter?  Both do the same thing.

Comment: Because I want to better my understanding of the syntax.

Comment: Not sure why this question was downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While [initially the plan was to have '&' available in SassScript](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ZJeOJGazgE) as a string that could be manipulated so that you could insert values wherever you wanted, [those plans have been abandoned for 3.3 due to complication](https://gist.github.com/nex3/8050187). Unfortunately you'll have to wait a while to be able to do this. At the moment '&' is immutable and just means "whatever the selector chain up to this point is".

**EDIT** (2020.02.15):

it is now technically possible to achieve this with recent versions of dart-sass:

```
@use "sass:selector";

@mixin unify-parent($child) {
    @at-root #{selector.unify(&, $child)} {
        @content;
    }
}

div.test {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;

    &:before {
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        content: "";

        @include unify-parent(":hover") {
            border: 1px solid salmon;
        }
    }
}
```

Sources:

- https://sass-lang.com/blog/the-module-system-is-launched
- https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector#advanced-nesting

Comment: here in 2020, trying to figure out if this is still a problem

Comment: answer amended above, this is now possible